Checkout with non-interfering returning customer login
In a drupal commerce shop, I want to provide a possibility for returning customers to log in without introducing an obstacle for customers who want to check out without having to click on button "guest checkout" first. This is considered bad practice. So instead of something like this

something like this:

Can someone point out how to do this?

A typical Drupal commerce checkout flow starts with a Login step, and this pane contains a single "Login or continue as guest" pane. Remove that pane and the Login step will be skipped because it's empty.
As per the example in your question, the first checkout step will now prompt the user to fill in their details. You can add an extra pane to the top of this step which displays a login prompt: "Already a customer? Login".
Create a custom checkout pane plugin which displays the login prompt if the user is not logged in. This should be a link to the login page with a destination query argument to bring the user back to checkout after they login i.e. /user/login?destination=checkout/{order_id}.
